# how to make invalid-feedback works with btn-group using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm having problem to show error on a radio button group when using Bootstrap's btn-group,
I wanted to have the error display under the button group, but I can't get it work (error not showing on validation).

The only way to have it work is to add the invalid-feedback inside the btn-group, but in this case it's very ugly when it appears (and more on mobile as there is less space).

Is there a way to somehow link that invalid-feedback with the input without having it in the same div as the input ?

Here is a part of my register form:

```html
<form class="needs-validation" id="profileForm" novalidate>

    <div class="card">
    
        <!-- title -->
        <h4 class="card-title mt-3 text-center">Register</h4>
        
        <!-- inputs -->
        <div class="card-body">
                
            <!-- ... -->
                
            <!-- gender --> 
            <div class="form-group">
            
                <label class="label" for="gender_group">Gender:</label>
                
                <div class="btn-group" id="gender_group" data-toggle="buttons" role="radiogroup">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-male" value="male" required>
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-male">male</label>

                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-female" value="female" required>
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-female">female</label>

                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-other" value="other" required>
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-other">other</label>

                    <!-- invalid-feedback works if I place it here but it's just ugly ! -->
                </div>

                <!-- invalid-feedback should be here to be positioned at the bottom of the group, but it won't show on validation -->
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please make a choice.
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <!-- // gender form-group -->   
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ... -->
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing feedback inside `btn-group` and add `flex-wrap` to its parent, `btn-group`, which will make feedback stretch full width in a new row.

However, that will make buttons stretch on invalid feedback toggle. To prevent that, you might make them always full parent's width (add exact width to btn group's parent, depending on the layout of your form, on different breakpoints).

or, you can use BS grid (tweak extra for different screens):

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="label col-2" for="gender_group">Gender:</label>
    <div class="btn-group col-6 flex-wrap"
```

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<form class="needs-validation" id="profileForm" novalidate>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- title -->
    <h4 class="card-title mt-3 text-center">Register</h4>
    <!-- inputs -->
    <div class="card-body">
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- gender -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="label col-2" for="gender_group">Gender:</label>
        <div class="btn-group col-6 flex-wrap" id="gender_group" data-toggle="buttons" role="radiogroup">
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-male" value="male" required>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-male">male</label>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-female" value="female" required>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-female">female</label>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="gender-other" value="other" required>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="gender-other">other</label>
  
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please make a choice.
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- // gender form-group -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </div>

</form>
```